Folder Creation in python using Graph creates empty child folder
I am trying to automatically create an amount of folders in a Sharepoint site.
Each time I call this function, it creates empty folder as well.
    def create_folder_in_drive(access_token, drive_id, parent_path, folder_name):
create_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{parent_path}/{folder_name}:/children'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
folder_data = {
    "name": folder_name,
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
create_response = requests.post(create_url, headers=headers, json=folder_data)
create_response.raise_for_status()
return create_response.json()

For example, if my folder structure would be : (Parent):foo->(child):bar, the result would be: (Parent):foo->(Children):foo,bar.
I have tried removing the :/children part, but it results in a 400 error. Any suggestions?

make sure your code is properly indented, and provide an example of how you use this function (and don't forget to remove secrets)
